# flutter get path without string quotes

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm using `final path = await getExternalStorageDirectory();` to get the external directory path. Then I've to contcat rest of file path to get the text file. But the output of `print('${path}/AppLog/Logs/28032022.txt');` are coming like below.

`'/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abc.myApp/files'/AppLog/Logs/28032022.txt`

I need to achieve the path like `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abc.myApp/files/AppLog/Logs/28032022.txt`.
How can I remove the `''` from the path. Due to this I can't get file.

Comment: String.replace() ?

Comment: It show Directory can't be string. For path there's nothing something like ``path.replace / path.replaceAll``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this `func` to concatenate the filename in the path:

```dart
  Future<void> getPathForFileName(String fileName) async {
    final path = (await getExternalStorageDirectory())?.path;
    final finalPath = File('$path/$fileName').path;
    print(finalPath);
  }
```

---

Test:

```dart
    getPathForFileName("AppLog/Logs/28032022.txt");
```

prints:

`"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.flutter_demo/files/AppLog/Logs/28032022.txt"`